# CSS Grid Styling

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to understand how CSS grids work. I've tried to make an example of a store item as practice, but I am at a loss.

Here's my how my CSS currently looks. Cut off at the top, weird spacing, and the right side is not coming together at all.

[image]

How's how it would ideally look

[image]

Here is my current CSS, I hope someone can help explain where I am misunderstanding the use of
CSS grids.

```
.store-currency {
    height: 3vh;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;

}

.currency {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

#num-bought-item0 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.store-item {
    height: 15vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    border: 5px white solid;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}

.store-item img {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 8vh;
}


.store-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30vw;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="store-container">
        <div class="store-item" id="item0">
            <div class ="item">
                <img src="dumbell.png" alt="">
                <span>Dumbbell</span>
            </div>
            <div id="num-bought-item0">
                <span>Owned</span>
                <span id="count-item0">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="currency">
                <img class="store-currency" src="coin.png" alt="">
                <span>100000</span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did the first steps.

> To get started you have to define a container element as a grid with display: *grid*, set the column and row sizes with *grid-template-columns* and *grid-template-rows*, and then place its child elements into the grid with grid-column and grid-row.

```
.store-container {
  display: grid | inline-grid;
}
```

- grid – generates a block-level grid
- inline-grid – generates an    inline-level grid

With grid-template-columns you can define how many columns will appear in your layout.
P.S  Fr unit is a fractional unit and 1fr is for 1 part of the available space. In this example each column would take ~ 25% from the available space.

```
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

For your task, you can use grid-template-areas feature.

> The grid-template-areas CSS property specifies named grid areas,
> establishing the cells in the grid and assigning them names.

For example:

```
.item-a {
  grid-area: header;
}
.item-b {
  grid-area: main;
}
.item-c {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
.item-d {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header"
    "main main . sidebar"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

This will generates something like that in modern browsers:
[image: grid-template-area]

If you need more examples, take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
Some of the examples are taken from the second site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing flex and grid properties. grid-row and grid-column are only avalaible for a grid display (2D), not a flex display (1D).

You can try to play around with flex (worse choice since it is drawing a 1D layout) , you can use grid , which is made for this kind of layout.
Here a couple example with flex and grid

```css
/* GRID make it simple*/
.grid {display:grid;}
#num-bought-item2 {grid-row:1/3;grid-column:2;}
#num-bought-item2 {display:grid;margin:auto;text-align:center}
/* layout done */

/* some reset for the demo*/
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.store-container {display:grid;justify-content:center;}
.store-item {border:solid;}
.store-item>div {padding:0.5em;}
img{vertical-align:middle;}
[src="https://dummyimage.com/25/ff0"]{border-radius:50%}
big{color:darkgreen;background:lightyellow;}

/* FLEX make it a mess */
.flex {display:flex}
.column {flex-flow:column wrap;height:120px;}/* here an height is to be set so it wraps*/

/* since it is not made for this, we need to mess around */
.flex #num-bought-item1{order:2}/* reorder item */
.flex .item {height:0;min-height:60%;}/* hide it, then show it */
.flex .currency {height:0;min-height:40%;}/* hide it, then show it */
.flex #num-bought-item1{display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;text-align:center;margin:auto;}
/* and flex did not do it */
```

```html
  <p>Let's try via flex</p>
  <div class="store-container">
  <div class="store-item flex column" id="item1">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50" alt="">
      <span>Dumbbell</span>
    </div>
    <div id="num-bought-item1" >
      <span>Owned</span>
      <span id="count-item1">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="currency">
      <img class="store-currency" src="https://dummyimage.com/25/ff0" alt="">
      <span>100000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>And via <big>grid</big> </p>
<div class="store-container">
  <div class="store-item grid" id="item2">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50" alt="">
      <span>Dumbbell</span>
    </div>
    <div id="num-bought-item2" >
      <span>Owned</span>
      <span id="count-item1">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="currency">
      <img class="store-currency" src="https://dummyimage.com/25/ff0" alt="">
      <span>100000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```